# Admob Free - Ionic 2 - Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, admob

I´m trying to use AdMob Free (cordova-plugin-admob-free) with Ionic 2 and Angular 2 but I am getting the following error all the time:

https://pastebin.com/Fj9b6cQc

To build the project I do the following:

1. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free
2. npm install --save @ionic-native/admob-free
3. Add this plugin to your app's module

In app.module.ts

```
import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AdMobFree
  ]
```

4. In home.ts

   ```
   import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private admobFree: AdMobFree)
   ```

And inside ngOnInit method:

```
const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      // add your config here
      // for the sake of this example we will just use the test config
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
      };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
      .then(() => {
        // banner Ad is ready
        // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Can someone help me?

Many thanks!

Edit: Problem solved! I had not updated the SDK. Sorry my fault :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  let adId;
  if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    adId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx';

    var option: any = {
      adId: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx',
      //size: 'SMART_BANNER',
      //position: admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      autoShow: true,
      isTesting: true,
    };
    console.log("option", option);
    this.admob.createBanner(option).then(() => {
      this.admob.showBanner(8);
    });

  } else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    adId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx';

    var option: any = {
      adId: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx',
      //size: 'SMART_BANNER',
      //position: admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      autoShow: true,
      isTesting: true,
    };
    console.log("option", option);
    this.admob.createBanner(option).then(() => {
      this.admob.showBanner(8);
    });
  }
  this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
    .then(() => { this.admobFree.banner.show(); });
```